# Boostrap 3 Html Css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a small issue I am using bootstrap 3

I need it to display as followed

> image--username ------------------------------------------ location

At full screen there is about a 3 inch gap between the image and username, when you resize it down the usernames first letter goes over the image around 1000px, when there is still room in the div areas. I've tried displaying the image as a block still no luck. I would like the image and username to be about 15px; away from each other until my break point.

My second issue I have researched but found nothing, in Firefox when the background image changes at breakpoint it flashes white, but does not do this in explorer or chrome.

> html

```
<div id="profile-hero-background" class="profile-hero-background">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">       
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="img-insignia" src="content/media/insignia/r1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <p>Moderator</p>
                    <h1>Jeff</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <p>Location</p>
                    <h1>United States</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> css

```
#profile-hero-background {
    background-color: #000; 
    height: 500px;
}
.profile-hero-background {
    background-image:url(../images/hero-bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}


.img-insignia {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {



  .profile-hero-background {
    background-image:url(../images/hero-bg2.jpg);
    background-color: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<div class="container">
```

and your missing a ending

```
</div>
```